# Entering USA on E3 visa more than 10 days before the start of the job

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas

I have a job offer from a USA company and I'm now in the process of applying for the E3 visa. The visa condition states that I can enter USA only 10 days before the start of my job.

Is there a way to enter USA earlier? I would like to go there 2-3 weeks before the jobs starts to look for an apartment and generally get my life organised.

Would it be possible to enter first on the tourist visa and then 10 days before I start my job go to Canada (I'll live very close) and re-enter USA on E3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically it would be possible, but in practice it may be interpreted by the CBP as an attempt to start working before your official visa starts. Generally it is not advised to enter the US in proximity to the H/E/L visa start dates.

10 days should be enough to rent a temporary place, or even hotel, if your company doesn't provide any relocation assistance. Then look for a permanent place. In some places 10 days is more than enough to find a permanent residence - in larger cities there always are apartment complexes with vacancies.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I suspected. 10 days doesn't seem a lot to me though, considering I'm moving my whole life to another continent for a few years at least. I've done that once already (when moving to Australia) and settling down takes a while.

Comment: Just wondering how did you go with the 10 days? I am moving to US from Australia and I was planning 30 days before my start date and bumped on this restriction.